# How can I change spaces to underscores and lowercase everything?

Tags: perl, shell, sed, awk

I have a text file which contains:

```
Cycle code
Cycle month
Cycle year
Event type ID
Event ID
Network start time
```

I want to change this text so that when ever there is a space, I want to replace it with a `_`. And after that, I want the characters to lower case letter like below:

```
cycle_code
cycle_month
cycle_year
event_type_id
event_id
network_start_time
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: is it "sed or awk" or "sed, awk or Perl"?

Comment: anything  that can solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into sed documentation some more and following advice from the comments the following command should work.

```
sed -r {filehere} -e 's/[A-Z]/\L&/g;s/ /_/g' -i
```

Comment: Corrected, my bad. Still a bit new to sed.

Comment: nor sure why it is not working with `\s` which is replacing all "s" characters with `_`.instead i used `s/ /_/g`. this had worked like charm.but still i will accept your answer.thanks a lot for the right direction.

Comment: Odd, updated the answer to reflect this. \s should replace all white space characters. Not sure why it didn't work in your environment.

Comment: how could we do this without using tr as levis commented?

Answer (score 12):

Another Perl method:

```
perl -pe 'y/A-Z /a-z_/' file
```

Answer (score 11):

`tr` alone works:

```
tr ' [:upper:]' '_[:lower:]' < file
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `perl` tag in your question as well. So:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print join('_', split ' ', lc), "\n";
}
__DATA__
Cycle code
Cycle month
Cycle year
Event type ID
Event ID
Network start time
```

Or:

```
perl -i.bak -wple '$_ = join('_', split ' ', lc)' test.txt
```

Comment: thats fine but is there a one liner for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use your shell, if you have Bash 4

```
while read -r line
do
    line=${line,,} #change to lowercase
    echo ${line// /_}
done < "file"  > newfile
mv newfile file
```

With [gawk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gawk_%28GNU_package%29):

```
awk '{$0=tolower($0);$1=$1}1' OFS="_" file
```

With Perl:

```
perl -ne 's/ +/_/g;print lc' file
```

With Python:

```
>>> f=open("file")
>>> for line in f:
...   print '_'.join(line.split()).lower()
>>> f.close()
```

Comment: where are you changing the case in this script?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ /abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_/" filename
```

Comment: I know nothing about sed. Just curious, do we have to type all those letters? Or we can use y/[A-Z] /[a-z]_/ in sed like in Perl? Or there're some sort of shorthands?

Comment: Initially I tried y/[A-Z ]/[a-z_]/ but that did not work.  I thought there may be a shorthand but I do not know of it.  Hopefully someone will be able to refine my suggestion.